# Get complete HTML of webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, webapi

I would like to take a complete snapshot of website using JavaScript, like the one a browser take when saving the page as HTML (picture below).

[image]

By using a simple script like `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, the HTML part of a website can be obtained. However, it does not contain the linked style sheets.

To achieve this, I guess I have to get all resources the website loads.
Is it possible?

Comment: yes, you're right ... the linked stylesheets need to be retrieved separately ... also any other external resources, like images, and scripts, url's in the stylesheets, imports in the stylesheets, etc

Comment: Thanks. [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) is exactly what I want. (I saw this question before, but I missed the the right answer because it was not at the top...)